# Connection refused exception when using HttpURLConnection in Play framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm using play 2.0.4, I need to connect to an url to see whether it's alive or not to make redirect decision.

```
public boolean checkServer(String strUrl){
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConn.connect();

        if(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == urlConn.getResponseCode()){
            urlConn.disconnect();
            return true;
        }else{
            urlConn.disconnect();
            return false;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error creating HTTP connection:" + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

In this case, the url that i use is localhost:9001, which is another play application. But then I received this error : Connection refused

Stack trace:

```
Error creating HTTP connection:Connection refused
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:203)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:290)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:995)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:849)
    at models.Backend.checkServer(Backend.java:19)
    at controllers.Application.index(Application.java:22)
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(routes_routing.scala:32)
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(routes_routing.scala:32)
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$5$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:1090)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:33)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$class.apply(JavaAction.scala:74)
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$5$$anon$1.apply(Router.scala:1089)
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anonfun$6.apply(Invoker.scala:126)
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anonfun$6.apply(Invoker.scala:126)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:17)
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:125)
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318)
    at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:179)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:516)
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:259)
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975)
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1479)
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

Can somebody please show me what was wrong here?

Thank you very much.

Comment: "Connection Refused" is pretty explicit. Either your other application was not actually listening on that port/address, or you have something else interfering, like a firewall or anti-virus software, etc. As a quick check try using telnet to see if you can connect to the listening app, e.g. "telnet localhost 9001"